# How to avoid telling people about my job?

Tags: conversations, politeness, saying-no

New people who I meet always ask what I do for work.  This question is normal and polite to ask, but I don't always want to tell people what I do for the following reasons:

1. My job is unusual, which prompts more questions and turns the whole conversation into more questions about my job. I would rather talk about something casual so both parties learn more about each other as people, not as professionals.
2. My job conveys a high-status position, which can create awkward social dynamics.  I would rather the conversation lead to common ground with someone, not to spotlight our differences.

I have tried just mentioning vague details about the field I work in, but the vagueness usually prompts more specific questions.  I don't want to lie to anyone.  So, how can I avoid telling people about my job?

Comment: Can you tell _us_ what your job is? It might help stir up some ideas... (and possibly additional questions ;-) )

Comment: @KateGregory Yes, there are some helpful answers there.  Thanks.  Did not find this question earlier.